# Deploy maven project on wildfly

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

I am trying to deploy a maven project on wildfly in the command line using
"mvn wildfly:deploy" but get this error:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.gyurmatag.adminsystem</groupId>
<artifactId>adminsystem</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>

    <!-- javax persistance -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.15</version>
    </dependency>







</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
        </plugin> 
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, sorry. updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JAVA_HOME is not correct. One of the plugin's dependencies is depending on system's jconsole:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>jconsole</artifactId>
  <version>jdk</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/jconsole.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Based on your screenshot you've set java home to the jre dir but it must be the sdk one. Apart from that, try to exclude this dependency, it should work anyway.